# Choose random string from different arrays

Tags: javascript, random, categories

I have a form with a drop down menu, which has some categories (as `string`). When the user submits the form, I want to display a random text from the category that the user choose, but I have no idea how to do that.

I did it for one category, but I don't know how to do it for subsequent categories.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--
var r_text = new Array ();
r_text[0] = "text1";
r_text[1] = "text2";
r_text[2] = "text3";

var i = Math.floor(3*Math.random())
document.write(r_text[i]);
//-->
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this ?

```js
function select(){
  var categories = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
  if(categories == "Funny"){
    var r_text = new Array ();
    r_text[0] = "funny_text1";
    r_text[1] = "funny_text2";
    r_text[2] = "funny_text3";

    var i = Math.floor(3*Math.random())
     document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = r_text[i];
  }else if (categories == "Serious"){
    var r_text = new Array ();
    r_text[0] = "Serious_text1";
    r_text[1] = "Serious_text2";
    r_text[2] = "Serious_text3";

    var i = Math.floor(3*Math.random())
     document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = r_text[i];
  }
}
```

```html
<select onchange="select()" name="" id="mySelect">
  <option>-----</option>
  <option value="Funny">Funny</option>
  <option value="Serious">Serious</option>
</select>

<div id="res"></div>
```

Comment: Okay perfect! One question, how can I delay the outcome? So if the category is chosen there should be a loading sign or somehow a delay, how can i do this? ;) Thanks!

Comment: yes you can with [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout).

Comment: I'm really new to javascript, so I have no idea where to place the timeout function or how to connect it.. :/

Comment: just read the docs that i gave you, and you'll understand for sure.

Comment: and how can i add more than two options? I tried adding up to 4 with "else" but it wont work.

Comment: with else if, for example if u want to add new categorie comedy just do  `else if (categories == "Comedy"){}`

Answer (score 1):

Well if you want a basic, non-database way to do this you could do something like the following:

```js
  var funny = ["AHAHAH.", "This is funny.", "Ok, don't judge."];

  var other = ["Quote 1", "Quote 2", "Quote 3"];


var category = funny;

var quote = category[[Math.floor(Math.random() * category.length)]];

document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = quote;
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Where the variable `quote` would be what you display and the variable `category` would be what the user picked.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend having an array of objects containing the quotes and any applicable tags that apply to them. Since many quotes could be a combination of funny, inspirational, patriotic etc.

You could use something like this:

```js
var quotes = [
    {
        'value': 'Ask Not What Your Country Can Do For You...',
        'tags': ['inspirational', 'patriotic']
    },
    {
        'value': 'It Ain\'t Over Till It\'s Over',
        'tags': ['inspirational', 'funny']
    },
    {
        'value': '60% Of The Time, It Works Every Time',
        'tags': ['funny']
    },
    {
        'value': 'Funny and serious quote',
        'tags': ['funny', 'serious']
    },
    {
        'value': 'Inspirational and serious quote',
        'tags': ['inspirational', 'serious']
    },
    {
        'value': 'All tags quote 1',
        'tags': ['inspirational', 'serious', 'funny', 'patriotic']
    },
    {
        'value': 'All tags quote 2',
        'tags': ['inspirational', 'serious', 'funny', 'patriotic']
    },
    {
        'value': 'All tags quote 3',
        'tags': ['inspirational', 'serious', 'funny', 'patriotic']
    },
    {
        'value': 'All tags quote 4',
        'tags': ['inspirational', 'serious', 'funny', 'patriotic']
    }
    
        // Etc...
    ];

var getQuoteButton = document.getElementById('get-quote');

function getQuote() {
  
    var currentTag, randomIndex, randomQuote;
    
    var matchingQuotes = [];
    
    var category = document.getElementById('quote-category').value;
  
    if (category !== 'all') { 
  
        // Iterate through list of all quotes
        for (var quoteIndex = 0, quotesLen = quotes.length; quoteIndex < quotesLen; quoteIndex++) {
        
            // Iterate through current quote's tags
            for (var tagIndex = 0; tagIndex < quotes[quoteIndex].tags.length; tagIndex++) {
          
                currentTag = quotes[quoteIndex].tags[tagIndex];
          
                if (currentTag === category) {
                    
                    // Add matching quotes to array
                    matchingQuotes.push(quotes[quoteIndex].value);
                
                }
          
            }
      
        }
      
        randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * matchingQuotes.length);
        randomQuote = matchingQuotes[randomIndex];
      
    }
  
    else {
        
        // If 'All' is selected, choose randomly from all quotes
        randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length);
        randomQuote = quotes[randomIndex].value;
      
    }
  
    document.getElementById('quote').innerHTML = randomQuote;
  
}

getQuoteButton.onclick = getQuote;
```

```html
<label>Select A Category
<select name='quote-category' id='quote-category'>
  <option value='all'>All</option>
  <option value='funny'>Funny</option>
  <option value='inspirational'>Inspirational</option>
  <option value='serious'>Serious</option>
  <option value='patriotic'>Patriotic</option>
</select>
<button id='get-quote'>Get Quote</button>
<div id='quote'></div>
```